# Argument of multiprocess.pool.apply raises error of being non iterable int while it's an int from a loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In a class function I have an iterable function that loops through all vectors of the given input data matrix. I do this by the indices as I keep track which points have been checked and to which cluster they belong. 
Now I tried to parallelize this and two problems arise:

```py
[pool.apply(self.expandcluster, args=i) for i in np.where(self._checked == 0)[0]]
```

Raises an error:

```py
TypeError: expandcluster() argument after * must be an iterable, not int
```

So I'm wondering how I can iterate through the function 'expandcluster()' by feeding it the indices of boolean vector which is affected by parallel processes.

Then I also probably need to worry about how the parallel processes affect the vectors. Multiprocessing tutorials/docs are very scarce about this topic however. As you can see I now try to iterate through the function, which does not return any, just changes two vectors.

```py
class A():

    def _init_(self):
         init stuff...

    def fit(self, x):
        self._checked = False * np.array(np.size(X, axis=0))
        pool = mp.Pool(8)
        [pool.apply(self.expandcluster, args=i) for i in p.where(self._checked 
         == 0)[0]]

    def expandcluster(self, pointIndice):
        self._checked[pointIndice] = 1
        self._clusterIDs = self.find_points(pointIndice)
```

It's for a special implementation of DBSCAN, an unsupervised clustering algorithm. The reason I structure the dataflow like this is that as I check a single point and it turns out to be a cluster center, I check all surrounding points in the same area. Now I don't have to check those again. 
I've first implemented the algorithm without parallelization, which works fine. I can use the extra computational power however. The original algorithm runs through a for loop with range(np.size(X, axis=0)).

Comment: [The following example demonstrates the use of a pool:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.successful) note the `pool.apply_async(...` line.

Comment: The example doesn't cover what I want to achieve. This question remains open. 
However I suspect it is not possible due the fact that my output is a single vector, and different processes sporadically change specific values within that vector.

Comment: The Error message should read: `TypeError: expandcluster() argument 'i' must be an iterable, not int`. Compare with the given link: `.apply_async(f, (10,))`